# WPF's WrapPanel like UI control for javascript/CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I'm a javascript/css container implementation similar to what WrapPanel is in WPF. Is there one?

pom

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of a `WrapPanel` (I am pretty new to WPF) is that the contents just flow. Which is just like inline elements in HTML.

So, all you need to do is style your elements inside a container to be inline and they should just flow, left-to-right, top-to-bottom